# How to continue writing to .csv when KEY/VALUE pair doesn't exist: KeyError

Tags: python, json, api, endpoint

Example of data:

```
[
{"fruit": "apple", "color": "red"},
{"fruit": "banana", "color": "yellow"},
{"fruit": "orange"}
]
```

My code for writing to .csv file:

```
for item in a["data"]:
    csv_file.writerow([item['fruit'], item['color']])
```

For the fruit 'orange', it doesn't have a 'color' k/v pair, so when my code hits that part of the JSON, I get an error:

KeyError: 'color'

**Is there a way to ignore that it doesn't exist for that object, and just keep writing the .csv file?**

Comment: There might be a better solution, but a try-except loop should work.

Comment: Try using try/except

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly check for `"color"` key presence:

```
for item in a["data"]:
    if 'color' in item:
        csv_file.writerow([item['fruit'], item['color']])
```

Or you can ignore a `KeyError` exception in that part of code:

```
for item in a["data"]:
    try:
        csv_file.writerow([item['fruit'], item['color']])
    except KeyError:
        pass
```